# Wait for navigation to end then dispatch an action with ngrx and rxjs

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

Here is the snippet :

```
  goToStep$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(RouterActions.goToStep),
      tap(({ path, query: queryParams, extras }) =>
        this.router.navigate([path], { queryParams, ...extras })
      ),
      map(() => RouterActions.nextOrBack())
    )
  );
```

I want the `RouterActions.nextOrBack()` to be dispatch only after the previous navigation is done.
How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: You can `concatMap` Router event `NavigationEnd`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `switchMap` (you can return promises in `switchMap`):

```ts
this.action$.pipe(
  ofType(RouterActions.goToStep),
  switchMap(({ path, query: queryParams, extras }) =>
    this.router.navigate([path], { queryParams, ...extras })
  ),
  // everything below is executed after this.router.navigate emits
  map(() => RouterActions.nextOrBack())
)
```

> `router.navigate` returns a promise that:
>
> - resolves to `true` when navigation succeeds,
> - resolves to `false` when navigation fails,
> - is rejected when an error happens.